# Same resource in two different servlets

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Is it possible to have the same resource in two different classes that are in two different servlets?

I want to do something like this:

```
public class One{
        @Resource(name="subscriptionService")
    private SubscriptionService subscriptionService;
}

public class Two{
        @Resource(name="subscriptionService")
    private SubscriptionService subscriptionService;
}

@Service("subscriptionService")
@Transactional
public class SubscriptionService {
}
```

There are two different servlet for class one and class two so there are two different instances of SubscriptionService.
Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>member-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>   

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>member-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

member-ws-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.pk.edu" />

    <!-- Uses the latest feature from 2.0.0 RC2. 
        Enables @Endpoint and related Spring-WS annotations. See Spring WS Reference 5.4-->
    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="pl.pk.edu" />-->
    <!-- SAAJ-specific implementation of the WebServiceMessageFactory. Wraps a SAAJ MessageFactory. 
    This factory will use SAAJ 1.3 when found, or fall back to SAAJ 1.2 or even 1.1. -->
    <beans:bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <!-- Requires a message factory so we declare one -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter"
            p:messageFactory-ref="messageFactory"/>

    <!--  See reference at the beginning of this document -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter"/>

    <!--  This is responsible for forwarding web service request to the correct adapters.
    This is exactly similar to Spring MVC's DispatcherServlet -->
    <beans:bean id="messageDispatcher" class="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher">
            <beans:property name="endpointAdapters">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:ref bean="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter"/>
                </beans:list>   
            </beans:property>
     </beans:bean>

     <!--  See reference at the beginning of this document -->
     <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="mappings">
            <beans:value>
                /ws=messageDispatcher
                /ws/subscription.wsdl=subscription
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property> 
    </beans:bean>

    <!--  See reference at the beginning of this document -->
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/> 

     <!-- Uses the latest feature from 2.0.0 RC2. 
        Enables interceptor endpoints. See Spring WS Reference 5.5.2
        Here we have an interceptor that validates XML request and a logger
        -->
     <sws:interceptors>
            <beans:bean id="validatingInterceptor"  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor"
                        p:schema="/WEB-INF/spring/wsServlet/subscription.xsd"
                        p:validateRequest="true"
                        p:validateResponse="true"/>

            <beans:bean id="loggingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
     </sws:interceptors>

    <!-- Uses the latest feature from 2.0.0 RC2. 
        Enables publishing of wsdl. See Spring WS Reference 3.7
        For dynamic location transformation to work, a special parameter must be added to the web.xml.
        The locationUri here has no use when integrated with Spring MVC because 
        it has been overriden by the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -->
    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="subscription"                                                           
        portTypeName="SubscriptionPort"                                                         
        locationUri="/"                                                       
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/subscription">                               
      <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/spring/wsServlet/subscription.xsd"/>                                                  
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <!--  Our mashaller. You can use any marshaller you want.
     For info on how to use Castor, see http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html#2.1-Marshalling-Behavior -->
    <beans:bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller"
        p:mappingLocation="/WEB-INF/spring/wsServlet/castor-mapping.xml" />

    <!-- Normally we use the GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter however if you read the Spring WS 2.0 API for this adapter:
     "Deprecated. as of Spring Web Services 2.0, in favor of DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter and MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor."
     See http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter.html

     So we have to implement using the recommended implementation. The advantage of these two classes is that
     we have a pluggable adapter. For more info, check the Spring WS 2.0 API and its source code.
     -->
    <beans:bean id="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="castorMarshaller"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="castorMarshaller"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <beans:property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
            </beans:list>   
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="methodReturnValueHandlers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:web-services="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.pk.edu" />
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Wczytanie beansow dla tiles oraz plikow konfiguracyjnych -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>



</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Depends on your context configuration. Please post it, both web.xml and your Spring context.

Comment: Yes you can. Have you at least tried it?

Comment: I added, I'm sorry for the mess in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `SubscriptionService` is defined in your `root-context.xml` then it should work.

Therefore you need to modify you component scan,  so that:

- the a component scan in `root-context.xml` finds that service but not `One` or `Two`no controller bean, and
- the component scan from the two servlets find `One` / `Two` but not `SubscriptionService`

Typicaly this this done by filtering (include and exclude )by the annotations:

`root-context.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="yourPackage">
    <context:exclude-filter
             expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
             type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

`servlet-context.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="yourPackage"  use-default-filters="false">
      <context:include-filter
               expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
               type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `DispatcherServlet` instances but want one single `SubscriptionService` bean. Change your configuration in both servlet context files so that they don't `component-scan` the `SubscriptionService` class. Instead put that `component-scan` in the `root-context.xml` application context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Since `DispatcherServlet` uses the context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`, the beans declared there will be available to it.